# Customize the Chromium file picker to sort by date, or make it remember past settings

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, chromium

I'm running Chromium 117 on Debian 12.2, using i3wm (so, no Gnome/KDE tools). Every time I need to upload a file in a web page, it opens the file picker, and sorts by file name. I find it annoying — I almost always want to have the most recent files appear first instead, because I'm much more likely to want to select a file I'm currently working on, or have just downloaded.

I seem to remember that when I was running Google Chrome on Ubuntu 22.10, the file picker would remember which sort order was applied last time I opened this directory, and chose this as a default, which makes a lot of sense. How do I get this behavior on Chromium/Debian? Alternatively, I'd also be OK hard-coding somewhere that I want more recent files to always show up first, but I don't know where to look.